# Adding properties to a CollectionItem to a descendant component

Tags: delphi, components, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I would like to create a descendant component from `TVirtualStringTree` and to add few more properties to `Columns` collection.

The actual structure of `TVirtualStringTree` is:

```
+ Header (TVTHeader)
|+ Columns (TVirtualTreeColumns)
 |+ CollectionItem (TVirtualTreeColumn)
  |- Text
  |- Width
  |+ Options
  |- CheckBox
  |- ... Here under [CollectionItem] I would like to add some more properties
```

Please some support about this topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive a new class from `TVirtualTreeColumn`:

```
type
  TMyTreeColumn = class(TVirtualTreeColumn)
    // add your desired properties as needed...
  end;
```

Then derive a new class from `TVirtualStringTree` and override its virtual `GetColumnClass()` method:

```
type
  TMyStringTree = class(TVirtualStringTree)
  protected
    function GetColumnClass: TVirtualTreeColumnClass; override;
  end;

function TMyStringTree.GetColumnClass: TVirtualTreeColumnClass;
begin
  Result := TMyTreeColumn;
end;
```